# Do I need to deploy both RPD on server to switch between these two through same OBIEE tool?

Tags: obiee

I am new to OBIEE tool , hence kindly bear with me if my query is basic in nature.
I have 2 RPD files, a.rpd and b.rpd. I need to switch between these 2 RPDs on same server and through same OBIEE tool.
Do I need to deploy both RPD on server to switch between these two through same OBIEE tool?

As per my own attempt, I can open both RPD file through Administration (obiee tool) : File --> Open-->Offline and without any deployment.

Is it mandatory to deploy both RPD at server to open it on line?

I guess I need to define 2 different ODBC system data sources for my repositories after deployment.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer to my queries through my own research, hence sharing in below so that others can be benefitted :

1)  OBIEE designed to work  with a single repository.
OBIEE has a single repository at any point in time. You can deploy A.RPD, use it and after a bit deploy B.RPD and use it. But it's either A or B and you will not have both on the server.

2)  You can merge A and B together (the Admin tool allows you to do that and you obviously need unique names inside both or they will override things) if you want to have A+B deployed.
it's possible to safely merge 2 RPD which would have different business models and different subject areas and different physical sources. In case of conflicts you must solve it: keep A or replace it with B. It's like when you have to manage conflicts in versioning control systems etc.

3)  However you can open both files locally,  "offline" mode , for that all you need is the file itself.

4)  It's also safer to work offline as you can do the whole work and then verify the RPD and only once you did everything you upload. If you work online and start doing changes but don't finish your work, people will be using an OBIEE system with a RPD half done. This could lead to errors. Also working online has some constraints because of how check in and out works.

Thanks,

Comment: Did you post the question in 2 places? https://community.oracle.com/thread/4330515

Comment: yes chris, was a bit urgent , hence tried to reach multiple experts.